# Nodejs websocket server Buffer issue

Tags: node.js, websocket, buffer

I'm trying to understand websockets. Recently i have spotted a problem with nodejs socket buffer.
I don't know if this is a feature or a bug.

Everything seems to work fine, before i'm starting to send requests pretty quickly.
Then i have noticed, that on server-side "websocket frames" are not separated, **both request** "frames" data was **inside one** buffer.

Should i clear the socket buffer right after receiving the frame or it should be cleared automatically?
If me, then how to do it? Nodejs doesn't have anything about clearing/releasing the buffer.

Here is the code:
https://gist.github.com/Somebi/a97c46761d9817f8353d

Comment: Google Chrome Dev Tools show me, that two frames were sent to the server. While on server-side, data event triggers only once...

Comment: Are you asking why you received two frames at once?  Or are you asking why a prior frame is still in the buffer when you get the second frame?  If the former, it is your responsibility to separate out frames.  The socket just delivers all the data it has for you.

Comment: Actually both questions. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading more about websocket spec, i have found information about Message Fragmentation.
Here is well formed information about it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers

Found my answers there.